# Vimscript insert after cursor

Tags: vimscript, insert-mode, options

I am aware of the `startinsert` command which switch to insert mode as if the `i` key was pressed. With the `!` it behaves like `A`.

Do you know if there is some kind of option to go to insert mode like we press the `a` key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround with manually detecting if the cursor is at the end of the line :

```
if col('.') == col('$') - 1
    startinsert! " `A`
else
    normal l     " `l`
    startinsert  " `i`
end
```

`col('$')` is the last column + 1 so if the cursor is at the end of the line we must substract 1.

reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19544043/2558252 (thanks to the robert-audi comment)